# How do I pass an array to a method?

Tags: java, arrays

I have not been able to find a proper answer on any forums about this.
But how exactly do I pass an array to a class constructor?

```
public class TestArray {
   String name;
   String[] array;

   public TestArray(String name, String[] anArray){
          this.name = name;
          int len = anArray.length;
          this.array = new String[len];
          for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
          {
              this.array[i] = new String(anArray[i]);
          }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] anArray = new String[2];
        anArray[0] = new String("Test");
        anArray[1] = new String("Test2");
        TestArray work = new TestArray("Jordan", anArray); // How to pass the array?
   }
}
```

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Haha, we were editing this question at the same time...

Comment: You have to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work, minus the question mark in the last line (edit - this was removed by the editor).

Your braces are also off - move the `main` function inside the class (you have one too many closing braces after the `TestArray` constructor).

**Edit 2** - now that your question has been edited to fix your errors, it should work as expected.  I am not sure if this is the best practice for SO, but that's a discussion for meta.

Comment: Wow this was exactly the problem. I had one to many braces and changing that one bracket made everything work. THANks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] anArray = new String[2];
    anArray[0] = new String("Test");
    anArray[1] = new String("Test2");
    TestArray work = new TestArray("Jordan", anArray);
}
```

This will work perfectly, although there is a shorter way to initialize `anArray`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] anArray = new String[] { "Test", "Test2" };
    TestArray work = new TestArray("Jordan", anArray);
}
```

Which in turn can be shortened to:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    TestArray work = new TestArray("Jordan", new String[] { "Test", "Test2" });
}
```

By the way, String objects are immutable, so you don't have to initialize new strings every time. They can be used directly like this.

Last tip: `Arrays.copyOf(anArray, anArray.length)` also returns a copy of the array, without the the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for copying the array.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you wrote...

### Update:

Maybe you got a compiling error, if so, you placed a closing braces (`}`) too much in your code. I removed it by formatting your code. Maybe this was the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects - so are passed them by reference. And you don't need to make copies yourself. If you really feel you have to copy then better use System.arraycopy.

Comment: 'so are passed them by reference'. close, but not true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: your reasoning is otherwise correct, but technically a reference is passed by value

Comment: @seanizer: agree - java passes references by value :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly? After you check the matching of {} (main must be into the class), and remove the ? after anArray, the program is compiled and work...: you passed the array correctly to the constructor... if you add

`System.out.println(this.array[i]);`

you will see your anArray content be printed as expected...

P.S. if your code was not for testing, but you wanted really to copy the array, use System.arraycopy like:

```
    this.array = new String[anArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(anArray, 0, this.array, 0, anArray.length-1);
```

See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for example.

***Errata corrige*** it must be `anArray.length` and not `anArray.length-1` since arraycopy wants the length, not the index as I remembered :)